# How to rotate a plane in 3D using Quaternion?

Tags: c#, kinect, quaternions

I am attempting to fuse skeletons from two separate Kinects.

From first Kinect I have `skeleton1`, from it I choose 4 points corresponding with 4 of it's joints. With those 4 points I can construct a plane  on which they all are. The plane coefficients `Ax + By + Cz = D` are known. As I understand the planes Quaternion would be `Q = (D; A; B; C)`

From the second Kinect I have the same data, but in second Kinects coordinate system.

How can I rotate the plane from second Kinect so that it would have the same orientation as the plane from the first Kinect?

Comment: Doesn't looks [simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation), nor `c#` related. More like [math](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/40164) question.

Comment: Quaternions, as they are used in computer graphics, represent rotation only. They cannot represent position or plane directly. Also, all quaternions representing a rotation have to be *unit quaternions* (i.e., the sum of squares of their components has to be 1). In your equation `Q = (D; A; B; C)`, that is by far not guaranteed, so I would conclude that it is, unfortunately, wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, quaternions don't work that way. They do not represent a plane, and cannot be created just by re-arranging the components of a plane equation (plane equation has two degrees of freedom, while quaternion is a non-parametric representation of rotation/orientation).

However, if you are looking for a rotation between two normal vectors (one for each plane), which will transform one plane to another, it is a relatively simple task:

- if the two normal vectors are the same, there is no rotation needed and the result is identity,
- if the two vectors are parallel (their dotproduct is zero) but *not* identical, the transformation between them is a rotation of 180 degrees around an arbitrary axis perpendicular to them,
- in all other cases, you can compute the axis of rotation using a crossproduct (and normalization), and the angle using arc cosine of their dotproduct.

If you still need to create a quaternion out of them, you can do it with a bit of [trigonometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation#Unit_quaternions).